# Print CSS properties to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<dd class="course_progress_steps" title="4 out of 7 steps completed">
   <div class="course_progress_percentage" style="width: 57%;"></div>
</dd>
```

How do I get:

1. the title - i.e. '4 out of 7 steps completed'
2. the width - i.e '57%'

and print them out in a div, for example:

```
<div class="css-info steps">4 out of 7 steps completed</div>
<div class="css-info percentage">57%</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this kinda escalated. Hope it's clear how it works.

```js
$('<div/>', {                    // create a div element 
  text: $('dd')[0].title,        // change the inner text
  class: "css-info steps"        // add a the class to the element
}).add($('<div/>', {             // create another element and add it together with the previous one
  text: $.trim($('.course_progress_percentage').attr('style') // get the text inside style, $.trim() removes white spaces from the beginning and end of the string
               .split(':')[1]    // creates an array and uses : as the splitting point ["width", "57%;"] and selects the 2nd array value
               .replace(';', '')), // remove the ;
  class: "css-info percentage"
})).appendTo('body');            // since both elements are now added together we can append them both to ex. body
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dd class="course_progress_steps" title="4 out of 7 steps completed">
  <div class="course_progress_percentage" style="width: 57%;">
  </div>
</dd>
```

Stuff you might want to know/learn

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- http://api.jquery.com/add/
- http://api.jquery.com/append/
- http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Also a quick read of the [jQuery Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) will really show you some of the basics

Comment: @Spokey this solution is too complex, there are simpler ways for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Document Object Model (DOM for short) allows Javascript to access and manipulate rendered HTML's attributes. [Quirksmode has a very helpful introduction](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) that goes over how to achieve things like this.

Let's deal with your example

```js
// document.querySelector allows us to get references to DOM elements using CSS selectors
// The '$' at the beginning of the variable names is a little convention to remind us it's a reference to a DOM element
var $course_progress_steps      = document.querySelector( '.course_progress_steps' );
var $course_progress_percentage = document.querySelector( '.course_progress_percentage' );

// getAttribute can get an attribute value from a DOM element
var steps      = $course_progress_steps.getAttribute( 'title' );
// style returns a CSSStyleDeclaration, which is a way of interfacing with element style
var percentage = $course_progress_percentage.style.getPropertyValue( 'width' );

appendCssInfo( 'steps',      steps );
appendCssInfo( 'percentage', percentage );

// A helpful function for creating elements with a class of 'key' and text of 'value'
function appendCssInfo( key, value ){
  // Create an element
  var $css_info = document.createElement( 'div' );
  
  // Add the classes we want
  $css_info.classList.add( 'css_info' );
  $css_info.classList.add( key );
  
  // Insert the text using appendChild & createTextNode
  $css_info.appendChild( document.createTextNode( value ) );
  
  // Append the new element to the document body
  document.body.appendChild( $css_info );
}
```

```html
<dd class="course_progress_steps" title="4 out of 7 steps completed">
   <div class="course_progress_percentage" style="width: 57%;"> 
   </div>
</dd>
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed comments Barney, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
$(".css-info steps").text($(".course_progress_steps").attr("title"));
$(".css-info percentage").text($(".course_progress_steps").css("width") + "%");
```

**Edit :**

the selector was bad in the first answer.
this is working.

```
$(".css-info.steps").text($(".course_progress_steps").attr("title"));
$(".css-info.percentage").text($(".course_progress_percentage").attr("style").trim().split("width:")[1].split(";")[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t0b8dqe2/1/

Comment: I couldn't get this to work Mathieu - do I not need an .after property?

Answer (score 0):

1)  document.querySelector(".course_progress_steps").title

2)  document.querySelector(".course_progress_percentage").style.width

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way calculating the width in %:

```
var width = Math.round($(".course_progress_percentage").width() / $(".course_progress_percentage").parent().width() * 100);

        $(".css-info.percentage").append(width  + "%");
        $(".css-info.steps").append($(".course_progress_steps").attr("title"));

      });
```

```js
$(function(){

  $('#button').click(function(){
    
    var width = Math.round($(".course_progress_percentage").width() / $(".course_progress_percentage").parent().width() * 100);
    
    $(".css-info.percentage").append(width  + "%");
    $(".css-info.steps").append($(".course_progress_steps").attr("title"));

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="course_progress_steps" title="4 out of 7 steps completed">
   <div class="course_progress_percentage" style="width: 57%;"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="OK"/>

<div class="css-info steps"></div>
<div class="css-info percentage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find these items and, accordingly, to obtain the required attributes and insert them as the contents, here is a small [demo](http://jsbin.com/gupijobimego/1/edit)